# Installing a specific package version with yum

Tags: installer, yum

I have a Fedora system with Postgres version 8.3 and I want to downgrade to 8.2 because of a compatibility issue.  I've been using yum for everything, but it's my first time with this package manager, and I don't know how to downgrade things.

So how do I tell it to give me a specific version of a package?

EDIT: I managed to get this working by following by [downloading](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.2.10/linux/rpms/fedora/fedora-9-i386/) the specific packages  as per skymt's suggestion, plus installing their GPG key.  All I had to do was

`rpm --import RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG

yum localinstall postgresql-8.2.10-1PGDG.f9.i386.rpm

yum localinstall .....`

And so on.  However, this was fairly clunky and I'm still hoping that there's an easier way.  If anyone knows of how to get YUM to target a specific version without resorting to this, please let me know so that I'll be able to do this next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Centos I did following this steps:

On /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo.

on Base and Update sections add the next lines exclude=postgresql* (then you don't update from normal repository for postgres rpm).

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=postgresql*

#released updates
[updates]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-5
exclude=postgresql*
```

Then download the version that you want. See http://yum.pgrpms.org/howtoyum.php

```
wget http://yum.pgrpms.org/reporpms/8.3/pgdg-centos-8.3-6.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh pgdg-centos-8.3-6.noarch.rpm
```

Now you have another repo in your /etc/yum.repos.d/  pgdg-82-centos.repo.

```
ls /etc/yum.repos.d/
CentOS-Base.repo  CentOS-Media.repo  pgdg-82-centos.repo
```

then if you install postgres, centos will take from yum.pgsqlrpms.org/

```
yum install postgresql postgresql-server
```

Answer (score 19):

From the manpage:

> MISC
>
> ```
>   Specifying package names
>
>          A package can be referred to for install,update,list,remove  etc
>          with any of the following:
>
>           name
>           name.arch
>           name-ver
>           name-ver-rel
>           name-ver-rel.arch
>           name-epoch:ver-rel.arch
>           epoch:name-ver-rel.arch
>
>           For example: yum remove kernel-2.4.1-10.i686
> ```

You may have to manually remove the newer version and then install the older.

Comment: My manpage for yum doesn't have this section.  Also, my version of yum doesn't have a "remove" command and uses "erase" instead.  Finally, I tried this for postgresql-8.2.10.i386 and every variation thereof which I could come up with and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the **upgrade** option and specify the version number:

```
yum upgrade postgresql-8.2.10
```

Check the dependencies list before hitting **Y**. You might need to add other packages to the upgrade list.

Answer (score 1):

A quick look at the man page revealed no such option. It seems they haven't added that yet; Yum is still a fairly young package manager.

Instead, download and manually install the [relevant RPMs](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/binary/v8.2.10/linux/rpms/fedora/fedora-9-i386/).

Answer (score 0):

I have heard that the [smart](http://labix.org/smart) package manager can do this. (haven't had the opportunity to try it yet). Yum is known not to support downgrading.

smart is available on fedora.